# Joining table in criteriabuilder by fields witch doesn`t have relations

Tags: java, jpa, specifications, hibernate-criteria

Let`s imagine situation that we have two classes:
Table User with columns:

id
name

And table Car with columns:

id
model
number
ownerId (no fk to User)

OwnerId is an id of a User. But we don`t have fk in db. So in our class Car in java code this field is Integer, not User.

The task is to sort cars by owner name and filter by model. If model is null - show all cars with sorting. We cant using Pageable because we don`t have field user.name in Car class. And don`t have relations to User from Car class.

But how to do it with specification and criteriabuilder? The main problem for me is to add sorting in specification. Thanks for answer.

I know how to do it using JPA and annotation @Query in repository. Smth like:

```
@Query("select c from Car c inner join User u on c.ownerId=u.id where c.model =:model order by u.name asc ")
```

```
@Query("select c from Car c inner join User u on c.ownerId=u.id order by u.name asc ")
```

The last one is for situation if we have null model. So without filtering.

I know how to filter car using specification:

```
public static Specification<Car> hasModel(String model) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        if (model == null) {
            return criteriaBuilder.isNotNull(root);
        }
        return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("model"), model);
    };
}
```

But how to add here sorting by user name?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You just need another one from (btw, won't work if you need left join):

```
return (root, query, cb) -> {
    Root<User> user = query.from(User.class);
    query.orderBy(cb.asc(user.get("name")));
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    predicates.add( cb.equal(root.get("ownerId"), user.get("id")));
    if (model != null) {
        predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("model"), model));
    }
    return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
};
```