# JPA Criteria Query with JOIN on Polymorphic Subclass

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have the following (simplified) data model:

```
@Entity
public class Person
{
    @ManyToOne Animal likes;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Animal{}

@Entity
public class Pet extends Animal
{
    @ManyToOne Home home;
}

@Entity
public class Domestic extends Animal
{
    @ManyToOne Farm farm;
}

@Entity public class Home {}
@Entity public class Farm {}
```

Now I want a  group the persons by home and count on different homes:

```
CriteriaBuilder cB = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cQ = cB.createTupleQuery();
Root<Person> person = cQ.from(Person.class);

Join<Person,Pet> jPet = person.join("likes");
Join<Pet,Home> jHome = jPet.join("home");
```

Here I'm getting the error
`Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [home] on this ManagedType [Animal]` the generated SQL query obviously explains why:
`INNER JOIN animal a ON person.likes_id = animal.id`. The next approach was to use `.treat`:

```
Join<Person,Pet> jPet = cB.treat(debit.join("likes), Pet.class);
Join<Pet,Home> jHome = jPet.join("home");
```

This seemed to be promising with the new `.treat` feature of JPA 2.1, but the generated SQL looks like this

```
INNER JOIN animal ON person.likes_id = animal.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN pet ON pet.id = animal.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN domestic ON domestic.id = animal
```

In fact it is joining all subclasses of Animal where I'm only interested in `Pet`. So I tried to limit to the specific class with a Predicate `cB.equal(jPet.type(),Pet.class)`. This generates some interesting SQL (which I have never seen before and where I wonder what is inserted in `END=?`)

```
WHERE CASE
  WHEN pet.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1
  WHEN domestic.id IS NOT NULL THEN 2
  WHEN animal IS NOT NULL THEN 0
  END = ?
```

But it still does not work as expected. How can I count the different home with JPA criteria queries where I start from a `Person`?

Comment: you may get two roots: `Root<Person> person = cQ.from(Person.class)` and `Root<Pet> pet = cQ.from(Pet.class)` and join them: `cB.equal(pet, person.get("likes"))`

Comment: Wondering sql statement is easier to understand with brackets ```where (case ...when ... then ... end) = ?``` So the return value of case statement must be equal to given parameter.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov: Can you please add this comment as an answer? Two roots .. interesting, but it works!

Comment: Can you please fix the syntax in `debit.join("likes)`? probably unclosed `"` - thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [may use multiple roots (mine: I believe that is the most common scenario)](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/2.2/apidocs/javax/persistence/criteria/abstractquery#from(java.lang.Class)) in `Criteria API` query:

> Create and add a query root corresponding to the given entity, forming a cartesian product with any existing roots.

So, your query might look like:

```java
Root<Person> person = cQ.from(Person.class);
Root<Pet> pet = cQ.from(Pet.class);
cQ.where(cB.equal(pet, person.get("likes")));
```

Moreover, that is not required to define `X-TO-Y` associations in order to write a query - we may [join "unrelated" entities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74810554/3426309) as well.